# Read data from bigquery with spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to read data from `bigquery` and print those. Here what I tried,

```
// Initialize Spark session
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .master("local")
  .appName("Word Count")
  .config("fs.gs.project.id", "bigquery-public-data")
  .config("google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable", "true")
  .config("fs.gs.auth.service.account.json.keyfile", "<key_file>")
  .getOrCreate()

val macbeth = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM shakespeare WHERE corpus = 'macbeth'").persist()
macbeth.show(100)
```

But this gives me an error as follows,

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: shakespeare; line 1 pos 14

Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException: Table or view 'shakespeare' not found in database 'default';
```

I couldn't find a way to fix this. Please help me to read data from this dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Table or view not found: shakespeare; line 1 pos 14

When BigQuery looks for a table it looks for it under the projectId and the dataset. In your code I see two possible issues:

1. projectId - You are using BigQuery public project as your projectId `bigquery-public-data` you need to change the value of this variable to a correct value
2. datasetId - In your query you didn't indicate the dataset which store  `shakespeare` table